# How filter rows on the basis of columns having searched text in QLineEdit and update it in QTableView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to filter rows on the basis of values present in column0, column1, column2 and column3 simultaneously and display it in the QTableView. But I can't able to filter text from any of the columns because of the error i.e.

```
 File "c:/Users/Shivani/Dropbox/My PC (10873-laptop)/Desktop/pyQt5 project/filter_model.py", line 25, in filterAcceptsRow    
    if not text.contains(regex):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

import sys
from random import randint, choice

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel, QRegExp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QFormLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QTableView,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

class SortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QSortFilterProxyModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.filters = {}

    def setFilterByColumn(self, regex, column):
        self.filters[column] = regex
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        for key, regex in self.filters.items():
            ix = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, key, source_parent)
            if ix.isValid():
                text = self.sourceModel().data(ix)
               
                if text != regex:
                    return False
        return True


def random_word():
    letters = "abcdedfg"
    word = "".join([choice(letters) for _ in range(randint(4, 7))])
    return word


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        tv1 = QTableView(self)
        tv2 = QTableView(self)
        model = QStandardItemModel(8, 4, self)
        proxy = SortFilterProxyModel(self)
        proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        tv1.setModel(model)
        tv2.setModel(proxy)
        self.layout().addWidget(tv1)
        self.layout().addWidget(tv2)

        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            for j in range(model.columnCount()):
                item = QStandardItem()
                item.setData(random_word(), Qt.DisplayRole)
                model.setItem(i, j, item)

        flayout = QFormLayout()
        self.layout().addLayout(flayout)
        for i in range(model.columnCount()):
            le = QLineEdit(self)
            flayout.addRow("column: {}".format(i), le)
            le.textChanged.connect(lambda text, col=i:
                                   proxy.setFilterByColumn(QRegExp(text, Qt.CaseSensitive, QRegExp.FixedString),
                                                           col))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that you use "contains", are you sure you have provided the code that generates this error?

Comment: please avoid useless imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP does not provide the line of code that generates the error but according to my experience it is trying to translate some code written in C++ (or an old version of PyQt4) where the texts are associated to QString that have the contains() method that accepts a QRegex but in PyQt5 the texts are python strings so they don't have that method. The solution is to implement the same logic using the indexIn method of QRegex:

```py
def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
    for key, regex in self.filters.items():
        ix = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, key, source_parent)
        if ix.isValid():
            text = self.sourceModel().data(ix)
            if regex.indexIn(text) == -1:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: Yes you are right ,this is working now but i am facing these kind of difficulties regularly , I have seen you answering almost all the answers of pyQt , How you became that much expert in it.